# Changing Gridview FilterExpression Dynamically

Tags: gridview, filter

This is my filter expression:

```
FilterExpression="User_roomID = '{0}'"
```

and this is my ControlParameter:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="User_roomIDFilter" ControlID="HRoomID"  DefaultValue="-1" />
```

HRoomID holds the index of the records I want to display. This works for existing records.

However, when I open a new form, HRoomID is blank, so the default value is "-1" and no records are shown.  (This is good.)  Then I process some information which generates a new value for HRoomID. However, FilterExpression does not update.

I have been unable to induce the filter to update. I've tried many solutions from the internet, including things like:

```
RoomID = "10";
DataSource1.FilterExpression = "[User_roomID] = '" + RoomID + "'";
```

(Written in C#).

Does anyone know how to dynamically change the filter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use following code on click event or page load as per you application requirement and change following parameter dynamically in program (.cs file):

```
DataSource1.FilterExpression = "User_roomID = '{0}' ";
```

//add filter parameter which select value from drop dropdown.

```
DataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("User_roomID", dropdown_room.SelectedItem.ToString());
```